# How to transfer 1-2MB from local to pod directory using Helm Charts?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Can anyone advise, is it possible to transfer 1-2MB file from local to pod using Helm Chart?

I tried using volumeMount and volume in the statefulset.yaml, then put the 1-2MB of files into a configmap, but I think the file is too big to mount it to the container. May I know whether is there other ways to transfer the files from local to container/pod by using Helm Chart?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/) a total size of Helm chart (including files) should be less than 1MB due to Kubernetes object size limit.

That also means you cannot store files larger than 1MB in `ConfigMaps` and `Secrets`.

You have several options. For example:

1. Make those files a part of container image.
2. Upload files to `PersistentVolume` and attach it to pod.
3. Upload files to some network location like HTTP server and download it to pod using `initContainers`.

Comment: may i know how can I make the files part of the container image? Sorry I am new to this.